# Why Altium designer autorouter making overlapped circuit track (error)?

Tags: altium, autorouter, tracking

I am using autoroute option in Altium designer (for  only bottom layer), but in result I see some tracks overlapped to each other, as you can see in this photo:

[image]

So I think when the Altium could not find proper route it must not make track between those two points, but this is not happening!
Why?

Comment: Have you asked Altium Support?

Comment: No, But I will do it soon.

Comment: Easy answer: Because autorouters suck. That routing is a mess, you'd be MUCH better off routing it by hand. Avoid autorouters -- they're more trouble than they're worth.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when Altium does something weird it is because of an incorrectly setup design rule, but unless you are prepared to spend ages on net classes and rule tweaking, manual is usually a much better approach, certainally if trying for a single layer layout.

I would also advocate some more thought about placement U3-U6 would route much more nicely if rotated 90 degrees anti clockwise

Comment: I think So (Altium does something weird it is because of an incorrectly setup design rule) but I guess there are some problem in some components library which make this error.!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an experienced PCB designer or Altium guru but by the look of the PCB it shows that you need to do these :

First of all remove THE ROOM(red box at bottom right) to change the green color of overall board, then you can see error better.
Green means design rule error.

Second , some of these tracks are not actually overlapped they are too close to each other. you can change this option on design menu->rules->Electrical->Clearance

Some of these are unroutable by Altium AI or you allow the software to short circuit in menu->rules->Electrical->Short Circuit

In the case you do not want to use upper layer which is a bad idea because you have to pay for two layer board, you should design bigger board or move some component and route it manually or use interactive route.

**PS** : Altium is a hard software to learn and need a lot of experience and these kind of confusion is normal for first few days and as a community we should be more patient about these kind of questions.